# Laravel 9: How can I use an existing validation rule inside a custom validation rule I created?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-9

I have a form field that can either be a username or an email. When the user submits this form I want to validate this field to see if it is a valid username or a valid email address. I already have a custom Username rule I created. But for this form, I want to create another custom rule called UsernameOrEmail. Inside this rule, I want to use the existing default email validation rule and my custom Username rule. How can I do this in Laravel 9?

I already saw in the docs that I can get the Validator instance as follows:

```
protected $validator;

public function setValidator($validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;

    return $this;
}
```

But then how do I actually make use of it?

Inside the `Illuminate/Validation/Validator` class, there's a method called `validateAttribute` that looks like it should solve my problem, but it's a protected method and so I can't actually call it from my custom rule class. It looks like I can only use the validator to validate all my rules at once, but not specific rules individually.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like the following in my custom rule class:

```
public function __invoke($attribute, $value, $fail)
{
    $is_email = $this->validator->validateAttribute($attribute, 'email');
    $is_username = $this->validator->validateAttribute($attribute, new Username);

    if (!$is_username && !$is_email) {
        $fail('The :attribute is not a valid username or email.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to just use a few rules separately? 

'username' => [new Username, 'email']

Comment: @PovilasKorop  not sure I follow. I can't use both the username and email rules for the same field because they have different validation criteria.

Comment: @user4181107, use the [validateEmail](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method_validateEmail) instead.

Comment: @jade  that's only half the battle. What about the username?